# How do I make metatag 'cp_address' call the gmap?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

The following script compiles advertiser fields 'cp_street', 'cp_city' and 'cp_state' to create the address that calls the sidebar map on my website. I have made a new field called 'cp_address' in which users can type the full address instead. How do I change the script below so that BOTH work?

```
   <?php
// check to see if ad is legacy or not and then assemble the map address
if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', true) )
    $make_address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', true);
else
    $make_address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_street', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_city', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_state', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_zipcode', true);

    $coordinates = cp_get_geocode( $post->ID );
?>

<script type="text/javascript">var address = "<?php echo esc_js($make_address); ?>";</script>

    <?php cp_google_maps_js($coordinates); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// check to see if ad is legacy or not and then assemble the map address
$make_address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_address', true);
if ( !$make_address || empty($make_address) )
    $make_address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_street', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_city', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_state', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_zipcode', true);

    $coordinates = cp_get_geocode( $post->ID );
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var address = "<?php echo esc_js($make_address); ?>";
</script>

<?php cp_google_maps_js($coordinates); ?>
```

Comment: Nope. Didn't destroy old street, city and state maps but single line addresses still cause the map not to show at all. The results are the same with the code you have given. (I cleared the browser cache and made a fresh post to test it.) How confident are you with this code? Could there be some kind of trait associated with the cp_street, cp_city and cp_state metatags? Or is your code just wrong? Thoughts?